# bash, issue with for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, ls

I'm listing some files from an amazon s3 this way:

```
s3cmd ls s3://my-bucket/$(date +%Y%m%d -d "1 day ago")*
```

this command returns:

```
2015-07-20 23:51  10680004   s3://my-bucket/20150720-1437436434_ip.log.gz
2015-07-20 23:55   6180965   s3://my-bucket/20150720-1437436477_ip.log.gz
```

In order to loop on these files, my code is:

```
for file in $(s3cmd ls s3://my-bucket/$(date +%Y%m%d -d "1 day ago")*)
do echo ${file}
done
```

but the result is:

```
2015-07-20
23:51
10680004
s3://my-bucket/20150720-1437436434_ip.log.gz
2015-07-20
23:55
6180965
s3://my-bucket/20150720-1437436477_ip.log.gz
```

instead of the expected result:

```
s3://my-bucket/20150720-1437436434_ip.log.gz
s3://my-bucket/20150720-1437436477_ip.log.gz
```

How can i retrieve the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
  $(s3cmd ls s3://my-bucket/$(date +%Y%m%d -d "1 day ago")*)
```

with

```
 $(s3cmd ls s3://my-bucket/$(date +%Y%m%d -d "1 day ago")* | sed 's/^.* s3/s3/' )
```

to replace the initial output by cutting off the date an size part.